# Correct permissions for Android in-app puchases

Tags: cordova, cordova-android

When trying to create the subscription within Google Play Console I get a message `To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to your APK` which I believe I've done.

I've added the following to my config.xml:

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
</edit-config>
```

And I've installed the the in-app-purchase-2 plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2) and added the billing key as mentioned here: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/wiki/Setup-for-Android-Google-Play#add-android-billing-key yet google play console still gives the error.

When I view the upload APK in App Bundle Explorer (within Google Play Console) I can see `com.android.vending.BILLING` listed in the permissions (image attached below). This leads me to believe I've granted the permission correctly. However, other permissions in the list don't have the `com.android.vending` prefix. Instead they have `android.permission` yet I haven't seen any `cordova` documentation to use anything other than `com.android.vending`.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

I'm using Ionic 5 with cordova-android ^9.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I performed the following tasks and the issue has resolved itself:

1. Uploaded a "release" APK (not "debug" APK)
2. Released the new APK as "Closed testing" not "Internal testing"